# D3 TypeScript set element to an attribute of the path element

Tags: typescript, d3.js

I can not compile the TypeScript code.

```
 var line = d3.line()
      .x(function(d,i) {
        return x(i);
      })
      .y(function(d) {
        return y(d);
      });

    graph.append("path")
      .datum(data)
      .attr("class", "line")
      .attr("d", line); // < !!!!!-------
```

I receive the error;

```
Argument of type 'Line<[number, number]>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ValueFn<BaseType, number[], string | number | boolean>'.
  Types of parameters 'data' and 'datum' are incompatible.
```

I do not what to do because the class Line does not implements ValueFn. I also do not see the declaration for such situation.

```
attr(name: string): string;
attr(name: string, value: null): this;
attr(name: string, value: string | number | boolean): this;

// element, in order, being passed the current datum (d),
attr(name: string, value: ValueFn<GElement, Datum, string | number | boolean | null>): this;
```

There is a part from the declaration file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This works. Set a line generator with data at once to the attribute.

```
let lineGenerator = d3.line<ILineChartPoint>()
      .x(function(d) { return x(d.x); })
      .y(function(d) { return y(d.y); });
...
let line = g.append("path")
      .attr("d", lineGenerator(this.data));
```

Comment: To add to this: `ILineChartPoint` seems to be a userdefined type. In my case it was simply `number`.